# R: number of consecutive 1s (from left to right)

Tags: r, pattern-matching

I have the following vectors pattern in R:

A vector of zeroes and ones (Binary vectors , each with length of 4), for example:

```
x <- c(1,0,1,1)
```

I would like to find number of consecutive 1(s) (from left to right, that is very important)

**Edit:** 
How to do it for matrix, at which each vector has the pattern mentioned above.
Preferably with base functions (and without any Rcpp like solutions)

Any pretty solution without *apply functions?

Comment: Why have you got pairs of 0,1 in curly brackets? Have you really got a 4x2 matrix or something? Construct the matrix in your question.

Comment: @Spacedman, which are notation would you use to explain that every vector value is either 0/1?

Comment: I would say "a vector of zeroes and ones, for example `x  = c(0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0)`. We all speak R here. Your question had no R code in it, or example data, so its hard to know what exactly you want.

Comment: @Spacedman, question fixed; please up vote (back to previous state)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this faster using Rcpp:

```cpp
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
int contiones(LogicalVector x) {
  int count = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < x.size(); i++)
  {
    if (x(i)) {
      count++;
    }
    else {
      break;
    }
  }  
   return count;
}
```

Note that I convert the input (implicitly) into a logical vector. If your input only consists of 0/1 values that shouldn't matter, but it will treat all other numbers the same as a 1. Add input checking as needed.

Testing in R:

```r
a <- c(1,1,1,0,1)
contiones(a)
#[1] 3
b <- c(0,1,1,1,0,1)
contiones(b)
#[1] 0
c <- c(1:5,0)
contiones(c)
#[1] 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
max(cumprod(temp1) * cumsum(temp1))
```

Example:

```
temp1 <- c(1,0,1,0)
max(cumprod(temp1) * cumsum(temp1))
#[1] 1

temp1 <- c(1,1,1,0)
max(cumprod(temp1) * cumsum(temp1))
#[1] 3

temp1 <- c(0,1,1,0)
max(cumprod(temp1) * cumsum(temp1))
#[1] 0
```

Comment: If anoyone has faster/more ellegant solution, I would like to know about it :)

Comment: `with(rle(temp_vector), lengths * values)[1]`. it's not very helpful to insert a picture instead of code. please edit the answer and add the code